# Inequality test returned unevaluated

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I tried,

```
Refine[Sin[k]^2/(k^2 + k + 1) < 1/(k^2), Element[k, Integers]]
```

> $\frac{\text{Sin}[k]^2}{1+k+k^2}<\frac{1}{k^2}$

It returns unevaluated. I tried converting Sin[x] into Taylor series but it still doesn't evaluate it.Is there some work around for this or is it that I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica returns this inequality:

```
In[1]:= ineq = Sin[k]^2/(k^2 + k + 1) < 1/(k^2);
```

unevaluated for integer `k` because it can be true, false or meaningless for different integers.

For positive (real not only integer number) it's true:

```
In[2]:= Refine[ineq, k > 0]
Out[2]= True
```

For 0 RHS doesn't exist and e.g. for -2 it's false:

```
In[3]:= ineq /. k -> -2
Out[3]= False
```

Comment: answer is correct, I got my mistake, I didn't mention domain for K.